# Splitting The Strings Of An Array Into Substrings And Inserting Them Into A New Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, stack

I'm currently struggling through a Java project (It has been a while) and I was hoping you all might be able to help.  I'm currently developing a stack manipulator/tokenizer for my project, and I'm having some issues with Arrays, String Arrays to be more specific.  Below is the code I've written, it doesn't include all the goodies on how I imported all the information from the text file, but I assure you it works and provides me with an array with each element being a different line:

```
package textfiles;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class modifierz {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        ArrayDeque<String[]> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        String file_name = "./input.txt";
        String temp = "";

        try {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

            for(int i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++)
                stack.push((aryLines[i].split(" ")));

             final int size = stack.size();

             for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
             temp = Arrays.toString(stack.pop());
             temp = temp.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", ""); //Clean up output.
             System.out.println(temp);//Test
             }

        }   catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is keeping all of this straight, I've gotten it to a point where this will print out each line of the input file, split into different substrings.  I just can't seem to get it to a point in which I can put all the substrings into a single array, and use that as the stack.  I keep goofing it up and having mismatches and such.  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What are the contents of `input.txt`? what is desired output and current output?

Comment: Do you want one element on the stack that is an array of all the words? Or do you want each word to be an element in the stack?

Comment: The input file will have lines such as push 10, push 20 or Add.  So I will need to identify if there is a command like push or add, and/or save integer values which I will save as strings and convert to integers or floats, later.  I want each word/character grouping to be its own element in the stack array.  I figure that will give me the most flexibility down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a better way to go about this all, took a new approach and figured out how to get this to end up with stack being fed the statements in reverse order of their appearance (sorta cheating, but whatever works).  I plan on establishing a temporary array to perform the actual computations and actions that need to be performed and then feed it back, but this should work:

```
package textfiles;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CommandCenter {

static void reverseArray(String arr[], int start, int end)    {
    String temp;
    if (start >= end)
        return;
    temp = arr[start];
    arr[start] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = temp;
    reverseArray(arr, start+1, end-1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String file_name = "./input.txt";

    try {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
        reverseArray(aryLines, 0, aryLines.length - 1);
        ArrayDeque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<String>(Arrays.asList(aryLines));
        System.out.println(stack);                                                      //TEST  

    }   catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in the second part of the code. You are calculating stack size inside for loop which executes on each execution of the loop and outputs decreased size each time due to pop() function. Please change it to:

```
 final int size = stack.size();
 for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    temp = Arrays.toString(stack.pop());
    temp = temp.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", ""); //Clean up output.
    System.out.println(temp);//Test
 }
```

Comment: Done, thanks for that I seem to have just gotten lazy at that point.